# Is it possible to connect to a https URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, websocket, python-socketio

I have a simple code running good using http (not secure) but then I update it to https a get an error about `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError`

I'm using a heroku server with a valid ssl of course, python 3.7.3 on a mac, `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`= 1.1.0, `certifi`=2019.3.9, `Flask`=1.0.2, `Flask-SocketIO`=3.3.2

Here is the code:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print('Connected ...')

@sio.on('message')
def on_message(data):
    print('I received a message!')
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect('https://heroku.server.url')
```

And this is what I get using https:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/calavraian/Devel/Projects/FlaskTesting/Client.py", line 21, in <module>
    sio.connect('https://heroku.server.url')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 208, in connect
    engineio_path=socketio_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 166, in connect
    url, headers, engineio_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 303, in _connect_polling
    if self._connect_websocket(url, headers, engineio_path):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 341, in _connect_websocket
    cookie=cookies)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 514, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 223, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 126, in connect
    sock = _ssl_socket(sock, options.sslopt, hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 260, in _ssl_socket
    sock = _wrap_sni_socket(sock, sslopt, hostname, check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 239, in _wrap_sni_socket
    server_hostname=hostname,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace of the error please?

Comment: Of Course, I just updated the post with the complete stack trace, thanks!

Comment: 1. If you think you should not provide the url then delete the tracebar url (it seems you noticed). 2. I just tested your code and it works correctly in Linux with python-socketio-4.0.1

Comment: Thanks for the advice @eyllanesc, The server url is not a problem in this case, because the server is just for testing this, I just updated to ```python-socketio-4.0.1``` but I get the same error an a mac with macOS Mojave (10.14.4) ... I'll try to test on a Linux.

On the other hand, I have tried to access the same URL from a terminal (from the same machine) using the command curl and the verification of the ssl certificate works well.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem I can connect to Heroku apps just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work, I tried the same code on another Mac computer with the same software condition and it works fine, also on a `PC with Ubuntu` and a `Raspberry Pi with Raspbian`, everything works fine, so back again on the first Mac with the problem, I started to debug again, reinstalling and updating packages with `pip` and nothing happened.

Other solution that I have tried was to reinstall the `certifi` package with `pip` but nothing was fixed.

At the end, what solved the problem was running the script that comes with Python and is located in `/Applications/Python 3.X/Install Certificates.command`, you can run it directly from `Finder` with double clic on it or on a terminal go to the folder and execute it.

After doing this I tested `python-socketio 3.1.2` and `python-socketio 4.0.1` and everything works fine.

A final recommendation, in case that you are still getting the same error after try running the script, you can try an alternative to `python-socketio`, in the process to figure it out I have tried `socketIO-client-2` when I was getting the error and this library worked good on the initial conditions (before running the script). After running the script above both are running perfect now.